# Why does reputation only carry over to meta?

Tags: discussion

I noticed something weird for the way reputation works across the different stack overflow networks. For stack overflow meta, the reputation carries over from the main stack overflow site. But for other networks; for example, sports; the reputation is separate apart from the starting 100 bonus for being trusted on another network. If you can't actually gain/lose reputation on meta itself, why does it even have reputation? Or why isn't it done like all the other networks?

Comment: So to clarify, you are wondering why meta sites inherit rep from their parent site, but completely different sites only provide the 100 point bonus for being a trusted user?

Comment: @psubsee2003 yes

Answer (score 7):

So you are really asking 2 separate questions.

**1. Why do you have the same reputation on Meta sites as the main site.**

Meta sites are seen as a semi-open site to help users ask questions and learn about how the main site works (provided they have 5 rep, or want to ask about their own question).  Reputation is a measure of trust that the community has in you.  So it makes completed sense that your main site rep be reflected in your meta rep.  You are the expert community on your site.  You don't want people from [Gardening.SE](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) or [Bicycles.SE](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/)  telling people how Stack Overflow should work.  Likewise, you don't want people who have meta rep without earning it on the main site telling you what you should be doing.

The "community" of the main site is exactly the same as the "community" of the associated meta site.  They aren't 2 separate sites, there are more like 2 parts of the same whole. The community of the meta site *must* be the community of the main site, otherwise you have a bunch of people with no experience on your site telling you how to make it work.

Every site has its own rules and its own idiosyncrasies.  So only someone who is an expert in a specific site should be telling you only about that specific site.  An expert only in a separate site can't tell you with any authority why Stack Overflow works the way it does (like I said before, you don't want a Gardening.SE user telling you why your SO question was closed).  So that user shouldn't have any privileges on MSO unless they earned them on SO.

If you are looking for a global meta (covering all sites, not just Stack Overflow), you should be looking for [Meta.StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), but that is for global questions only.  Questions about a specific site should be asked on that community's meta.

**2. Why do I get bonus reputation on new sites I join when I have enough reputation on another site**

What you are seeing here is called the association bonus. The idea here is that you are considered experienced enough in how Stack Exchange sites work to be granted the minimum privileges on every site.  You basically have enough rep to comment, flag, upvote, and remove the basic "new user" restrictions, but you don't have enough rep to downvote or do anything else that requires a basic level of understanding in the specific community.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the reasoning for the second part. For the first part, I'm wondering why they don't have meta rep as the sum of rep on all networks? Because meta is supposed to apply to all of them right?

Comment: @CaryShindell absolutely not.  Every site has its own rules and its own idiosyncrasies.  So only someone who is an expert in a specific site should be telling you about that specific site.  If you are looking for a global meta (covering all sites, not just Stack Overflow), you should be looking for [Meta.StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)